# How to draw Scene object in Unity inspector

Tags: unity-game-engine, serialization, scene, inspector

I need to view and manipulate with a Scene object (from a new SceneManager) in an inspector.
Even when I try to serialize it using

```
[SerializeField]
Scene scene;
```

the scene still doesn't show in the inspector.
Since SceneManager is fairly new (Unity 5), there is not much information out there and we would like to refrain from referencing scenes as strings, like we used to.

Answer (score 1):

Just storing a path string is inadequate, because if the scene file is renamed you've lost your reference. We can use an Object reference to the [SceneAsset](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneAsset.html) but we no longer have access to [`AssetDatabase`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AssetDatabase.html) to look up the path when not in editor.

To reliably handle both file renames and runtime paths you need two serialized  pieces of data (Object reference in editor, string path at runtime). You can create a `SceneReference` object that uses [`ISerializationCallbackReceiver`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ISerializationCallbackReceiver.html) to ensure that the stored path is always valid based on the specified SceneAsset Object.

---

As an example, here is my Implementation: https://gist.github.com/JohannesMP/ec7d3f0bcf167dab3d0d3bb480e0e07b

For good measure I added a [`PropertyDrawer`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PropertyDrawer.html) which displays the scene's build state and provides some convenient quick actions for managing it:

[image]

Each button has a tooltip, has destructive action confirmation dialogues, and respects the VersionControl checkout state of `EditorBuildSettings.asset` (tested with [Perforce](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/perForceIntegration.html)).

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.Scene.html) the Scene object is only a Run-time data. Therefore it is only available when open or at run-time. You would probably draw an custom inspector for the fields you want to manipulate.

If you just want to get the Scenes defined int the BuildSettings 
you could work with the `EditorBuildSettings.scenes` in the `UnityEditor` namespace. Create a custom Inspector Field (like a [Enum Popup](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorGUILayout.EnumPopup.html)) to only choose by the scenes defined in the BuildSettings.

You could also work with `SceneSetup` which you can retrieve from `UnityEditor.SceneManagement.EditorSceneManager`. But this will only allow you to manipulate loaded data in your scene or at runtime, too.

You could create a Wrapper Class for the Scene Object and draw a custom [Property drawer](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/editor-PropertyDrawers.html) for it. You then would need some class to manage the user input in the fields to properly save the data in the actual Scene object.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this plugin https://github.com/uurha/BetterSceneManagement, this plugin allows you to serialize scene assets in inspector and load them asynchronously